# How to reword any commit's message given the following message format?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I need to modify a commit's message given the commit id without changing any other commit info. However, the commit message should accept line breaks,etc similar to how it is done using the `git commit` command.

For example, consider the following commit

```
commit <id>
Author: <user-name> <user-email.com>
Date:   ...

    Hello World
```

I want to reword the commit message to this

```
    Hello World

    Text after line break1
    More text
```

The normal method would be to rebase interactively, and then edit the commit using `git commit --amend` or perform a reword operation on that commit. However, this will modify commit info such as committer email, time etc.

*(Check the update section for rebase)*

Filter-branch in git will allow to rewrite the commit by only changing the commit message and ids as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27699824/10155936).

But, how do I reword a commit with the above commit message format using filter-branch ?

**Update:**

Here's an example for interactive rebase.

- Create a test repository with 2 commits

  ```
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ git init
  Initialized empty Git repository in /home/test/temp_git/.git/
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ touch file1
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ git add .
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ git -c "user.name=A" -c "user.email=a@xyz.com" commit -am "Add File1" --author="B <b@xyz.com>"
  [master (root-commit) f122a34] Add File1
   Author: B <b@xyz.com>
   1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
   create mode 100644 file1
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ touch file2
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ git add .
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ git -c "user.name=B" -c "user.email=b@xyz.com" commit -am "Add File2" --author="B <b@xyz.com>"
  [master 3b023cf] Add File2
   1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
   create mode 100644 file2
  ```
- Commits created above have different author and committer. The complete log is as follows :

  ```
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ git log --format="fuller"
  commit 3b023cf256ae3498fbaf740329d94842143a5e4a (HEAD -> master)
  Author:     B <b@xyz.com>
  AuthorDate: Tue Oct 15 08:28:07 2019 +0530
  Commit:     B <b@xyz.com>
  CommitDate: Tue Oct 15 08:28:07 2019 +0530

      Add File2

  commit f122a341e31691f3170207c9a452ff18846fe120
  Author:     B <b@xyz.com>
  AuthorDate: Tue Oct 15 08:27:22 2019 +0530
  Commit:     A <a@xyz.com>
  CommitDate: Tue Oct 15 08:27:22 2019 +0530

      Add File1
  ```
- Performing interactive rebase as user A and rewording the root commit

  ```
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ git -c "user.name=A" -c "user.email=a@xyz.com" rebase -i --root
  [detached HEAD 228b423] Add File1 (test)
   Author: B <b@xyz.com>
   Date: Tue Oct 15 08:27:22 2019 +0530
   1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
   create mode 100644 file1
  Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
  ```
- Updated log with the changes in committer info

  ```
  test@ubuntu:~/temp_git$ git log --format="fuller"
  commit 0d5e6a5fed5b22fc5f8e310c6e98b1e6b8a821b8 (HEAD -> master)
  Author:     B <b@xyz.com>
  AuthorDate: Tue Oct 15 08:28:07 2019 +0530
  Commit:     A <a@xyz.com>
  CommitDate: Tue Oct 15 08:31:41 2019 +0530

      Add File2

  commit 228b423e3e511c5954823e42df51a6f6acae91cf
  Author:     B <b@xyz.com>
  AuthorDate: Tue Oct 15 08:27:22 2019 +0530
  Commit:     A <a@xyz.com>
  CommitDate: Tue Oct 15 08:31:28 2019 +0530

      Add File1 (test)
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27699824/10155936), the following script can be used to reword the commit using filter branch:

```
#! /bin/bash
REV=$1
MESSAGE=$2
FILTER="test $(echo '$GIT_COMMIT') = $(git rev-parse $REV) && echo $MESSAGE || cat"
git filter-branch --msg-filter "$FILTER" -- --all
```

`usage: ./script_name.sh <commit-id> "commit message"`

However to add line breaks to the new commit message, I had to modify the commit message to this: `"$(echo -e 'summary_line\n\nmessage\nmore_message')"` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5064753/10155936). 
The above command adds two line breaks after the `summary_line` as per the general convention for [commits](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion).

Furthermore, the script had to be modified due to the escape sequence characters as mentioned in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27699824/10155936):

`$MESSAGE` in this line `$(git rev-parse $REV) && echo $MESSAGE` is changed to `\"$MESSAGE\"`

So the final command if the script name were `reword-commit.sh`, (to be run inside the git repository)

```
./reword-commit.sh <commit-id> "$(echo -e 'Hello World\n\nText after line break1\nMore Text')"
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify a text file for the `$MESSAGE` text? And this text file will contain new line characters and apostrophe characters.

Comment: @Mr-IDE Probably something like this should help `./reword-commit.sh <commit-id> "$(echo -e '$(cat /path/to/file)')"`

Comment: Just to let you know, this does not work: `./reword-commit.sh <commit-id> "$(echo -e '$(cat /path/to/file)')"` - It gives error: "`cat: /path/to/file: No such file or directory`" . **However this works fine:** `./reword-commit.sh ABC123 "$(cat /path/to/file.txt)"` . On a separate note, the first part of your answer says to use "`echo $MESSAGE`" , but the second part says to use "`echo \"$MESSAGE\"`" . So which one should we use?

Comment: @Mr-IDE First part just quotes another answer, the second part talks about what modifications were needed to get it working for my case. For this `It gives error: "cat: /path/to/file: No such file or directory" ` - probably you didn't give the aboslute path of the file containing the message.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my recommendations:

1. (Preferred) Don't do it. Don't worry about old commit messages and just be better at new ones.
2. `filter-branch` way that you showed in your answer.
3. Impersonate (this will still affect commit timestamps):

   1. Change your git config to have the name and email of original author of the commit.
   2. `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://linuxize.com/post/change-git-commit-message/).

You can do an interactive rebase using `git rebase -i HEAD~N`, which  will display "N" commits.
You can then go to the commit line you wanna change and rename `pick` to `reword`.

After this, you adjust the commit message in the upcoming editor.

[**NOTE**]

It is not recommended to change/rebase pushed commits because you have to `force push` and other people have to merge/re-clone the repository.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I would request you to go through the question again, I have already mentioned about interactive rebase

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari I know but I think that this way of rebase(`reword` instead of `amend commits`) does not change the user info.