# GIT: How to edit/reword a commit message, while keeping the fastforward history of branches

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history, git-amend

I have a fast-forwarded repo history with branches, representing server upgrade states.

```
branch2
|
commit4
|
commit3
|
branch1
|
commit2
|
commit1
|
initial commit
```

If I rebase from commit1 to reword the commit2 message, then after rebase I will have the following history:

```
branch2
|
commit4
|
commit3
|
|              branch1
|              |
|              commit2_reworded
|              |
|              commit1
|             /
|           /
|         /
|       /
|     / 
initial commit
```

How to reword a commit message, which is several fast-forwarded branches earlier, while keeping the straight history line?

Can not reconnect back branch1 to commit3 as it was originally?

Comment: Long story short : you can't. Commits embed the ref to their parent. If the parent changes, it changes. No other way around this.

Comment: Can not reconnect branch1 to commit3 as it was originally?

Comment: There is a workaround using ```filter-branch```. You can check my Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58327105/10155936) (But note that commit ids will change)

Comment: You can reconnect them, but `commit3` and `commit4` will change in that process.